# Duplicate output with arrays in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to gather the data from 6 stocks in the array, but when my API can find the data I want it to move to the next item but still selecting just 6.
I tried with this code and other variants but nothing seems to work. The output always duplicate one stock and I don't know why

```
portfolio = ['NVDA', 'SPCE', 'IMGN', 'SUMR', 'EXPE', 'PWM.V', 'SVMK', 'DXCM']
tt = 0
irange = 6;
for i in range(irange):
    try:
        t = requests.get('https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/profile?symbol='+portfolio[tt])
        t = t.json()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error calling API, waiting 70 seconds and trying again...")
        time.sleep(70)
        t = requests.get('https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/profile?symbol='+portfolio[tt])
        t = t.json()
    try:
        coticker = t['ticker']
        coexchange = t['exchange']
        coname = t['name']
        codesc = t['ggroup']
        coipo = t['ipo']
        cosector = t['gsector']
        costate = t['state']
        coweburl = t['weburl']
    except Exception as e:
        print("Information not available")
        irange = irange+1
    print("THE TT IS:"+str(tt))
    tt = tt+1
    print("")  
    print(coticker,coexchange,coname,codesc,coipo,cosector,costate,coweburl)
```

This is the output:

---

THE TT IS:0

NVDA -- GATHERED DATA

Information not available

THE TT IS:1

NVDA -- GATHERED DATA

THE TT IS:2

IMGN -- GATHERED DATA

THE TT IS:3

SUMR -- GATHERED DATA

THE TT IS:4

EXPE -- GATHERED DATA

Information not available

THE TT IS:5

EXPE -- GATHERED DATA

---

---

As you can see, when there is no information available, it doesn't move to the next one, it repeats the same one. What's the mistake? Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Your posted code doesn't use `portfolio` or `tt`.  We can't tell how it's supposed to "move to the next item", or what you mean by "selecting just 6".

Comment: @Prune Thanks for your response. The SECRET word that makes the api call uses `portfolio[tt]` for refering to the stock doing the call. Like **http://api.com/call?stock=** `portfolio[tt]`

Comment: How does using the string `'SECRET'` use `portfolio[tt]`? Show your actual code, since that's probably where the problem is.

Comment: The thing is that I just want to gather the data from first 6 items in the array. When the API cant find the data of one specific company in the array the code displays **information not available**. I want it to move to the next stock and instead it selects and makes the call for the same stock again. Sorry for not clarifying before.

Comment: Use `for symbol in portfolio[:6]:` to loop over the the first 6 items in the list.

Comment: No you didn't. Update the code in the question to show how it's actually done.

Comment: @Barmar Done, just updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207858/discussion-between-ivan-achille-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the line that prints the information inside the `try` block that sets all the variables. Otherwise, you'll print the variables from the previous stock.

To make it keep going past 6 items when you have failures, don't use `range(irange)`. Loop over the entire list with `for symbol in portfolio:`, and use a variable to count the successful attempts. Then break out of the loop when you've printed 6 stocks.

I've changed the code to use `if` statements instead of `try/except` to handle empty responses.

```
portfolio = ['NVDA', 'SPCE', 'IMGN', 'SUMR', 'EXPE', 'PWM.V', 'SVMK', 'DXCM']
irange = 6
successes = 0
for symbol in portfolio:
    try:
        t = requests.get('https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/profile?symbol='+symbol)
        t = t.json()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error calling API, waiting 70 seconds and trying again...")
        time.sleep(70)
        t = requests.get('https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/profile?symbol='+symbol)
        if t:
            t = t.json()
    if t:
        coticker = t['ticker']
        coexchange = t['exchange']
        coname = t['name']
        codesc = t['ggroup']
        coipo = t['ipo']
        cosector = t['gsector']
        costate = t['state']
        coweburl = t['weburl']
        print("")  
        print(coticker,coexchange,coname,codesc,coipo,cosector,costate,coweburl)
        successes += 1
        if successes >= irange:
            break
    else:
        print("Information not available for "+symbol)
```